# Override registry mentioned in publishConfig of package.json through command line

Tags: npm, npm-publish

I have lot of packages with different publishConfig, I am trying to move them to a new artifactory and I can't change them all. Is there a way to override the publishConfig through command line?

Answer (score 4):

Looking at `publish()` in https://github.com/npm/cli/blob/581b60b51ce0a30328fc582a4903b5d570c5d494/lib/publish.js, it appears that there is no way to override `publishConfig` information from the command line. The `publishConfig` information is read from `package.json`. `opts` is updated based on that and is not updated from another source (like command line flags) after that. So the `publishConfig` in `package.json` has the final say.

Comment: I actually had to write down a script to remove PublishConfig from every package. Thanks for the help